# How can I calculate Mean anomaly from True longitude?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements, physics, calculation

So, I have

**- TLE data 

 - Reference frame: `QMOD` 

 - Type: `Osculating`

 - Semimajor axis 

 - Eccentricity 

 - Asceding node 

 - Argument of Perigee 

 - True longitude**

I must calculate **`Mean Anomaly`**, just I need formula

Comment: I think it would be better if you explained more what you are trying to do. Mixing a TLE and osculating elements doesn't make sense. Why don't you actually show, or explain what you have more clearly.

Comment: @uhoh I have TLE data and reference frame. Just I need formula for converting from **true longitude** to **mean anomaly**

Comment: You have TLE? But TLE entry of line 2 columns 44–51 is the value of mean anomaly, in degrees!

Comment: There are a lot of questions like this, and I think someone should do a definitive 'elliptical orbit' answer, explaining how to compute values, talking about things like the Equation of the Center, and so on. Or maybe just link to a good resource, something like http://www.stargazing.net/kepler/ellipse.html

Comment: @sf. yes, I know/ but I need formula to calculate

Comment: @iLLkeeNNemo: `cat tle | tail -n +1 | head -n 1 | cut -c 44-51` ? How does one write a formula for a given?

Comment: @barrycarter thank you, but I haven't found the formula yet

Comment: @sf. that's problem. I have TLE data, and other data. I wanna check data manually, so I need formula for this

Comment: @iLLkeeNNemo: Ooooh. So you want to *verify*, not *find* the value. That makes a difference.

Comment: Hopefully, the link I provided noted that there is no closed form formula to convert mean anomaly to true anomaly. You need to numerically solve an equation.